# TryCatch Activity catches an exception caught and not rethrown further down the call stack?

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

Consider something like this:

```
protected overrid void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
{
    try
    {
        // this method can throw exception, but it's OK for rest of the Workflow
        UserStore.PrepareUserData(WorkflowData.Get(context).SecurityID);
        [...]
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Logger.Write(string.Format("There was an exception while preparing execution data for user ID: {0}. Operation ID: {1}", WorkflowData.Get(context).SecurityID, context.ActivityInstanceId), "Workflow, 3, 305, TraceEventType.Warning, "PrepareDataActivity");
    }
}
```

Exception thrown by UserStore.PrepareUserData method is being caught inside try..catch block in CodeActivity. The problem is the higher level try..catch activity catches that caught exception.
Is it possible to prevent catching this exception at higher level?

Comment: An already caught exception will never been caught again in a higher level catchblock, if it is not rethrown.

Comment: Are you sure that `UserStore.PrepareUserData` is throwing the exception? Maybe it's `WorkflowData.Get` and you're calling this again in the `catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to prevent catching this exception at higher level?

That is exactly what you're doing in your example.

This:

```
catch (Exception exc)
{
    Logger.Write(string.Format("There was an exception while preparing execution data 
                                for user ID: {0}. Operation ID: {1}", 
                                WorkflowData.Get(context).SecurityID, 
                                context.ActivityInstanceId), "Workflow, 3, 305,
                                TraceEventType.Warning, "PrepareDataActivity");
}
```

Is swallowing the exception, it isn't re-throwing it using `throw`. This means that the top level `catch` block won't actually catch anything, as it was already handled at your lower level block.

Answer (score 0):

During debug of each item in xaml activity I've found bug in next If activity which caused exception handled in TryCatchActivity. I was checking variable against null using something like this:

```
SomeVar = Nothing
```

instead of

```
SomeVar is Nothing
```

Anyway thank you all for your effort.